# Is the title of Randy Newman's "You've got a friend in me" Grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I'm a native english speaker and "you've got a friend in me" *sounds* correct to me but I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what kind of construction it is. Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: "in me" is a prepositional phrase modifying "friend".  'You" is the subject, "have got" is the verb, "friend" is the object.

Comment: "What a friend we have in Jesus" is the name of a well-known hymn.

Comment: You buy a home in London. You find comfort in ice cream. You have a friend in me.

Answer (score 2):

As a guest on Grammar Girl’s blog (https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/is-have-got-acceptable-english), Bonnie Trenga explained, “The phrases ‘has got’ and ‘have got’ are somewhat informal and are often contracted, as in ‘He’s got’ and ‘They’ve got.’ Although this expression has long been criticized as an unnecessary substitution for the verb ‘to have,’ it is perfectly idiomatic. It simply adds emphasis.” The emphasis is useful in song lyrics: “You have a friend in me” would have been OK in Randy Newman’s song, but *got* lends itself to being accented better than *have* does. Carole King made the same choice in her song “You’ve Got a Friend.”

Comment: I like your explanation a lot more than Bonnie Trenga's.  "I've got ten dollars" is no more emphatic than "I have ten dollars."  But the difference in prosody makes the phrase worth keeping.

Comment: Grammar Girl is an American, and her column is generally about American English. In fact this column specifically says that *have got* is more common in the U.K. than in America. It's not frowned on in the U.K. any more than it is in the U.S.

Comment: Got is definitely not "frowned upon" in the UK, for casual or informal speech.

Comment: Lynne Murphy is an American-born linguist living and teaching in the UK. I'm just reporting what she said.

Comment: Well, her being an "American-born linguist" gives her no particular authority, and it seems she is capable of getting it wrong. "You've got" is actually more common in casual British English than in US English.

Comment: I'm the one who got it wrong. I looked it up in her book, and "have gotten" is what she says the British hate. I edited that out of the answer. Also, Bonnie Trenga is not Grammar Girl, and I made that explicit.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: speaking as an American, it's hard to imagine that *you've got* is much more common in casual BrE than it is in casual AmE (where it is incredibly common). [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you%27ve+got%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cyou%27ve+got%3Aeng_gb_2012+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20%27ve%20got%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20%27ve%20got%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cyou%20've%20got%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20've%20got%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0). For formal English, I definitely believe it.